# How to know if a project is C or C++ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-construction

How does Visual Studio know if a project is C or C++? Is there any configuration or build parameter that indicates this ?

Does VS use C compiler for C, and C++ compiler for C++ ?

Comment: The file endings. Files ending in `.c` is compiled as a C file. However, the C-mode of the compiler is not very up to standard, it doesn't even fully support the C99 standard (14 years old that it is).

Comment: I have had bad experiences mixing C and C++ in the same project.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It doesn't claim C99 support. It's C89.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's kind of my point. If you want a good and up-to-date C compiler you wouldn't use the one in VS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does VS use C compiler for C, and C++ compiler for C++ ?

## No

the `cl` compiler is smart enough to know(based on file extension) if a file is a `.cpp` or `.cc` file - which it considers as C++ file. And the `cl` compiler will consider a `.c` file as a C program source file, and compile accordingly. Although it does load a separate `dll` file for compiling `C` and `C++` file. But this is implementation defined.

However, there is a switch to override the behavior of `cl` based on file extension.

To compile as C++ source file (even with extension of `.c`), command would be:
`cl /TP yourfile.c` **note however, the file should contain valid C++ code.**

And to compile as C source file (with extension of `.cpp`), command would be:
`cl /TC yourfile.cpp` **note however, the file should contain valid C code.**

Comment: The project settings will also allow either C++ or C to be forced on all files.

Comment: does `cl` follow the gcc extensions as well? ie `.c` is a C file and `.C` is a C++ file?

Comment: nope, @Mike, windows file system is case insensitive. And `cl` will follow the same :-)

Comment: @DrewDormann yes, there is a setting in nmake if I am right. But I hardly use nmake - I use `cl` through-out my project. with build files in perl

Comment: Yeah, I know *Windows* is case insensitive, but that doesn't mean they couldn't check file extensions case sensitivity; but of course that would mean Microsoft would have to be ***thinking*** about cross compatibility, and I know that's asking too much. :)

Comment: @Mike I tried compiling a valid C++ file with extension of `.C` and - guess I was right. It still thinks I was compiling C file instead of a C++ file. And gave a bunch of errors

Comment: @Mike - Windows is not case insensitive in itself, it is just the *default* when creating a file. If you want something else, check out the FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS option for CreateFile. Some people are thinking about compatibility!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from extension, if you go to `File Properties->Advanced`, there's a `Compile As` option, which may be used to explicitly treat the code as C code.

It generates `/TP` for C++ and `/TC` for C.

As Joachim noted in comments, though, VC++ isn't exactly the most conforming compiler on the planet, so picking "whatever works" might be actually a reasonable option.

Answer (score 0):

There are no C or C++ projects. Any project can have C, C++ and other language files mixed.

It is not clear what kind of answer to the second question you are expecting. The C language is compiled with a C compiler and the C++ language with a C++ compiler. It is hard to imagine what other cases are possible. The two compilers may or may not be implemented as a single executable program, but this is a rather uninteresting minute detail.